# Python: fastest and easiest to use db for 5,000,000+ cached html pages and pickled dictionaries

Tags: python, html, database, performance, caching

I'm working on a crazy project which heavily caches html pages and it also caches all the parsed data. The parsed data is in the form of dictionaries.

Currently I have a very primitive storage implementation: I created an EXT4 partition and I'm storing each data set in a separate file there. When I omit some unimportant details, I can say that my primary key is the file name.

This is obviously far too slow and I arrived at the point of development where I can't continue like that for performance reasons.

At first SQLite seemed the way to go, but keeping the story short, the fastest implementation I could come up with (after reading a lot how to speed it up) was slower than my current one-file-per-entry approach. I can't switch to python3 where SQLite is supposed to be faster and have better support for concurrent access (when I remember correctly).

**So here is what I need:**

- speed, speed, speed
- Same as with SQLite, I must be able to set the location of the database file in one or two simple python calls (forget MySQL, where you have to do trickery on operating system level)
- fast concurrent r/w access
- easy to use well documented python interface

**In addition it might be helpful to know that:**

- [edit:] data is few times greater in size than RAM
- when I cache html the primary key is the url (string)
- when I cache a dictionary object, the primary key is int
- I plan to use pickle module to store dictionary objects
- I don't plan to use any text compression since it would slow down the access. I rather have a huge database file which can be accessed fast.
- Since it's caching, I have to check very frequently if a key exists
- Sometimes I have to iterate over 500,000 entries
- While iterating those 500,000 entries I must be able to make fast concurrent inserts
- On average I have estimated 20 concurrent reads (but lots of them per thread or process)
- most of the access is key-value access, there will be some minor filtering in the future (for example get all entries which are older than 1 month)
- access patterns can be considered random (there are no entries which are accessed much more frequently than others)

Recently I stumbled upon pickleDB, but I suspect, it will not scale...

Comment: *"This is obviously far too slow"* - Why? In-memory filesystem caching exists so things like rapid access to plain old files can still be very fast. Perhaps you need to tune your system for aggressive filesystem caching.

Comment: Not making this as an answer but perhaps redis or something like it might be a better fit?  Checking if a key exists in redis or similar key:value storage systems is ridiculously fast.  One additionaly benefit is that redis ( or memcache ) can drop old/stale data as space demands, so no need for additional cleaning scripts.

Comment: @evolution I have used redis for problems similar to yours, a quick way to figure out if it will work for you is to take the largest block of data and the average of data then multiply that plus 30% for worse case demand.  Keep in mind you need that much actual ram as redis stores everything in memory with 30 to 90 backups to disk.

Comment: Sometimes I need to access up to 10% of all files depending on what I aggregate. Those 10% might fit into RAM. Average case is 1%. Once something is aggregated, the result is stored and not recalculated for a longer period of time.

Comment: Nope, I just gave up on redis. Not suited for my problem at all. The result was horrible. 10x slower and RAM was spilling over after only 100 MB of data, resulting in: (error) OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory' when I tried to limit memory usage. I think it is unable to deal with any data that isn't in memory.

Comment: Anyone? Before I start possibly wasting my time with CouchDB...

Comment: Looks like I'm going to answer my own question soon. CouchDB turned out to be the winner (once I got it working). The default configuration already matched per-file access speed and I could surpass that very soon with a couple of tricks such as paralellization and generating my own *.ini files. I will describe what I exactly did once I find the time.

Answer (score -1):

### NEW ANSWER August 2022

specificaly designed for key value storage:

Use MongoDB [Full tutorial Explaining how to add documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/getting-started/)
if you want to store pickled data from python i suggest not doing so, as binary data and encoding decoding(un-pickling) take more compute from processor.